# Question about parametric, implicit equation and vector equation

Tags: analytic-geometry, parametric, solid-geometry

what is 2 form at below image
it is implicit equation and vector equation? or parametric?
how to convert implicit form to vector form?
how to find the angle of plane in the best way?

[image: math question]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Also, please don't include vital information as images.  Use MathJax to properly format the mathematics so that it is easier to read and easier to search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first equation is a standard Cartesian equation of a plane with normal vector $(3,4,2)$.

The second plane is given in parametric form; from this form you cannot immediately read off a normal vector, but you can easily get two direction vectors (coefficients of the parameters $t$ and $s$); namely $(1,2,-1)$ and $(1,1,1)$. The cross product of these two give you a normal vector of the second plane.

The angle between the two planes is the same as the (sharp) angle between the two normal vectors, if they form an acute angle. If you find an obtuse angle, the angle you're looking for is its supplementary angle.

Comment: i quite loss in past i study

explicit equation
y=mx+b

implicit equation
ax+by+c=0

normal
a.(x-p)

parametric
p+tv

Comment: That's a (Cartesian) equation of a _line_ in the _plane_; your question is dealing with _planes_ in (three-dimensional) _space_.